# Series representation of a differential form

Tags: definition, differential-forms

I have a problem understanding the general series representation of a p-form.

For 1-form things are pretty clear to me: For $h = (h_1, \dots, h_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ h = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} h_i e_i $ one has: 
[image: General Series Representation of a 1-form]

However one may generalizes this to p-forms and gets for: $h_j = (h_{1j}, \dots, h_{jn})$ and $ j = 1, \dots, p $ : 
[image: General Series Representation of a p-form]

with the wegde product here $dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_p}$ usually referring to the determinants.

Choosing however $n = 3$ and $p = 2$ gives me the problem that $3 \times 2 $ matrix for which the determinant isn't defined. Thus either the series representation stated above is flawed (something I don't believe) or $n = 3$, $p =2 $ doesn't make any sense and/or my understanding is flawed.

Thus I would be very happy, if someone could point out my misconception. As always any constructive comments, answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when $n=3$, you're still just dealing with a $2\times 2$ matrix, albeit now there are 3 *of* them!

Notice that the sum is over choices of numbers $1\le i_1 \le i_2 \le 3$ (in your case). Therefore, there's a term with $i_1=1$ and $i_2=2$, one with $i_1=2$ and $i_2=3$, and one with $i_1=1$ and $i_2=3$.

In each of the three terms, the determinant you take comes from the square matrix that you get by choosing *just two* of the three columns, and then idea is that any $p$-form can be represented as a combination of these forms. (These $p\times p$ "subdeterminants" of the $p\times n$ matrix are usually called its "maximal minors.")

When $p=1$, by the way, you can see that your matrix is just a long row, and you only get to "choose" one column. Therefore, you just choose a single one of your $x_i$'s. The maximal minors of a row vector are just each of its entries.

Comment: Yes, this makes most sense. Thus one should get $\binom{n}{p}$ determinant terms in general.